# How to get All unstructured fields of MongoDB using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have some data stored in MongoDb, that currently I do not want to map on POJO,
How we can get all unstructured fields of Documents in a single map.

I found this link 
http://www.carfey.com/blog/using-mongodb-with-morphia/

that says you can mapped all unstructured fields using

```
// .. our base attributes here
private Map<String, Object> attributes
```

but its not working as I am contiguously getting it null,
I checked the Morphia code, It iterates on Morphia entity class fields, so how can we get all DBObject unmapped fields in attributes Map.

Comment: currently thinking to make specific field with @NotSaved anotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of interest: Why would you do that? You'll need to map the class and the one field, in which you want to add your data, to Morphia anyway. Or am I misunderstanding you?

How to do it:
You'll need to annotate all fields you want to store in the map with `@Transient` and add / load them in your custom `@PrePersist` and `@PostLoad` methods.

Comment: Just for educational purposes